# Can I replace my 2"x4" rough opening for a door with a 1/2"x4" to accomodate a new door jamb that's too wide?

Tags: framing

Can I replace my 2"x4" rough opening for a rough opening made with 1/2"x4" to accomodate a new door jamb that's too wide?  Will the 1/2" x 4" opening be enough to support the new double door that I plan to install?

Comment: Probably be better to move the rough opening over more.  Is it a load bearing wall?

Comment: A picture of the current opening with some indication of what part you're planning on replacing would be most helpful. It's highly unlikely, though, that a 1/2" thick board, on its own, is going to support much.